# Browser loading icon stays spinning after route handlers finish running (nextjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have Route Handlers for Save and Edit. Let's just look at Save for now. I have a client component that's a form the user fills out, and when they click submit, the `handleSubmit` runs.

```js
const handleSubmit = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const res = await fetch("/api/saveRecipe", {
                method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    title: title,
                    time: time,
                    time_unit: timeUnit,
                    serves: serves,
                    ingredients: ingredients,
                    instructions: instructions,
                }),
            });
            const data = await res.json();
            if (data.status == 200 && res.ok) {
                router.push("/");
            } else {
                console.log(data.error);
                setLoading(false);
                setError(true);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message || e.description);
        }
    };
```

As you can see, I call my route handler in this submit function and I get a json response from it and if its fine, I redirect the user to "/".

Here is my route handler

```js
import { createRouteHandlerClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
export async function POST(req) {
    const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies });
    try {
        const data = await req.json();
        const { recipe, error } = await supabase.from("Recipes").insert(data);
        if (error) {
      return NextResponse.json({error: "error from supabase", status: 500})

        }
    } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({error: "error in try catch", status: 500})

    }

    return NextResponse.json({status: 200})
}
```

This logic works fine. However a very annoying bugs occurs is that when I click submit, my browser starts loading the request (tab icon turns into loading spinner) and then I get the response from the route handler and get redirected to "/". Now theoretically, the browser loading spinner should stop loading. But it doesn't.

It's like something hasn't finished running but as you can see all my functions return an appropriate response. So theres something running in the background and I have no clue what. My website runs "fine" but the loading spinner keeps spinning unless I refresh the page. And this makes my site unusable when I deploy cuz it says "this Serverless function timed out"

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the isLoading() state to false when you get status code 200. I think you should set the isLoading to false after receiving any response whether it is StatusCode 200 or another status code.

```js
const handleSubmit = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const res = await fetch("/api/saveRecipe", {
                method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    title: title,
                    time: time,
                    time_unit: timeUnit,
                    serves: serves,
                    ingredients: ingredients,
                    instructions: instructions,
                }),
            });
            const data = await res.json();
            if (data.status == 200 && res.ok) {
                setLoading(false); // add this line because the loading state should be false when you receive any response.
                router.push("/");
            } else {
                console.log(data.error);
                setLoading(false);
                setError(true);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message || e.description);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Nah this just affects a loading state in my app not the loading state of my browser (loading spinner)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).